# Promedio para algunos registros en sql

Tags: sql-server

```
tag         bloque    sector    valor     fecha
temperatura   01   invernadero 19.5   06-09-2018 08:00
temperatura   01   invernadero  20    06-09-2018 08:30
temperatura   02   invernadero  18    06-09-2018 13:30
temperatura   02   invernadero  25    06-09-2018 14:00
```

Tengo una base de datos así, necesito sacar el promedio de la temperatura por bloque.

Comment: ya probaste con AVG? sobre la columna que quieres el promedio?

Comment: Podrias por favor contarnos que cosas probaste y no funcionaron?

Answer (score 0):

lo logre de esta manera haces un **GROUP BY** por el campo bloque y aplicas **AVG** al campo valor:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLATEMPORAL (
    tag VARCHAR(20),
    bloque VARCHAR(2),
    sector VARCHAR(20),
    valor DECIMAL(10,2),
    fecha DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #TABLATEMPORAL VALUES
('temperatura','01','invernadero', 19.5, '2018-09-06 08:00'),
('temperatura','01','invernadero', 20, '2018-09-06 08:30'),
('temperatura','02','invernadero', 18, '2018-09-06 13:30'),
('temperatura','02','invernadero', 25, '2018-09-06 14:00')

SELECT bloque, AVG(valor) AS promedio FROM #TABLATEMPORAL GROUP BY bloque

DROP TABLE #TABLATEMPORAL
```